# Install mailgun bundle in Symfony 3.4 but getting unrecognized option "endpoint" error

Tags: php, symfony, swiftmailer, mailgun

I trying to install the mailgun bundle into Symfony 3.4 but getting an error.

First I downloaded via composer the following packages:

```
"cspoo/swiftmailer-mailgun-bundle": "0.4.*",
"php-http/guzzle6-adapter": "^1.1",
"php-http/httplug-bundle": "^1.4",
"azine/mailgunwebhooks-bundle": "*"
```

I see that they are installed in the vendor dir of Symfony. Then I added the bunble to the AppKernal.php.

```
new cspoo\Swiftmailer\MailgunBundle\cspooSwiftmailerMailgunBundle(),
```

Last I added the following configuration settings to config.yml of Symfony:

```
  cspoo_swiftmailer_mailgun:
  key: "key-xxx"
  domain: "mailer.xxx.nl"
  endpoint: 'api.eu.mailgun.net'
  http_client: 'httplug.client'

  swiftmailer:
    transport: "mailgun"
    spool:
        type: file
        path: '%kernel.root_dir%/spool'
```

But when sending a mail or running a command on the symfony commandline I getting the following error:

> Unrecognized option "endpoint" under "cspoo_swiftmailer_mailgun"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to have locked your version to 0.4 (`composer show cspoo/swiftmailer-mailgun-bundle` will show the current;y installed version).

The `endpoint` option was added in version 1.2.0.